# Need CSS for disabled button

Tags: css, button

Following is a button class im using in my application. Can someone make a class for disabled button?

```
.myButton {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #f9f9f9), color-stop(1, #e9e9e9));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9 5%, #e9e9e9 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9 5%, #e9e9e9 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9 5%, #e9e9e9 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9 5%, #e9e9e9 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #f9f9f9 5%, #e9e9e9 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f9f9f9', endColorstr='#e9e9e9',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#f9f9f9;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#666666;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:6px 24px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #ffffff;
}
.myButton:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #e9e9e9), color-stop(1, #f9f9f9));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #e9e9e9 5%, #f9f9f9 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e9e9e9 5%, #f9f9f9 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #e9e9e9 5%, #f9f9f9 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #e9e9e9 5%, #f9f9f9 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #e9e9e9 5%, #f9f9f9 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#e9e9e9', endColorstr='#f9f9f9',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#e9e9e9;
}
.myButton:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

Thanks, i would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary disabled">Disabled Primary</button>
```

the above is the code for disabled button in bootstrap 
or css pointer-events:none; in the button makes button disabled

Comment: im looking for simple css class that will make my button look disabled.

Answer (score 1):

```
 **Simple code to disabled button**  
  <button type="button" disabled>Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: this doesnt work because of the class applied to button. i need another class to give disabled look to button